# Determining encoding type in url

Tags: html, json, encoding

I am parsing urls that have the following form:

```
http:\/\/domain.com\/?key1=value1&amp;key2=value2
```

You can see that all the `/` are encoded as `\/` and all the `&` as `&amp;`. It is easy to hardcode this replacement to get the real url, but there may be some other characters encoding differently. I am looking for the type of this encoding so that I can handle the cases I am currently not able to predict. Are you aware of this encoding standard?

Comment: This looks like possibly JSON embedded in HTML?! You really should *know* the steps needed to decode something, not wildly guess. Where did you get this from?

Comment: Thank you for taking your time! It's from the wild web. There is no API so am left to guessing. Are you aware of any JSON to HTML standard specs? Google suggests the replacement method (and omits the need for replacing &amp;, so I have low trust in it)

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse engineer it, here are the steps needed to get the values.

```
$str = "http:\/\/domain.com\/?key1=value1&amp;key2=value2";

$str = htmlspecialchars_decode($str);// Convert &amp; to just &
$parts = parse_url($str); //Seperate Url string to its parts 
parse_str($parts['query'], $params); // Parse the parts to get the query params and set them to a new out &params 

//Loop though different params
foreach($params as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . " = " . $value . "</br>"; 
}

//Output
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
```

Comment: The thing is, I do not know all the possible characters that need to be decoded. This is why I am trying to find out which standard is used

Comment: Given the example provided my solution works, I suggest using it or your own version to test it over a few thousand examples and see if there are any hiccups and go from there, but I don’t foresee any

Comment: Meaning to automate it over that few thousand